# Laravel Fetch App Constants from DB in Controller Constructor

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

With my App I have 5 variables that my need to be changed periodically so I create a table for those variables in the DB so we can update them when ever needed and in the controller associated with one or two of those variables I fetch the variable value from the database in the controller constructor method and assign it to another variable `$distance` to use it within other controller functions and Database queries as shown in below

Get the variable from Database :

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{


    private  $distance;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->distance = AppConstants::where('id',1)->value('is_available');
       
    }
....
```

And use it as in function :

```
 public function ListNearByRes()
    {
        
  
        $res = DB::table('res_profile as r')
                ->where('r.distance','<',$this->distance)
                ->select(......)->get();
           
            return response()->json(['status_code'=>1000,'data'=>$res,'message'=>null],200);
        
    }
```

The code is working fine, but I just wanna ask if this is the best and ideal way to do it ? and if there is any other approaches for my situation

Answer (score 2):

I saw a lot of solutions out there, but this is what I prefer:

Add a configuration file inside your config folder and name it like `global-var.php`, then add your configuration:

```
<?php
return [
    'distance' => 'value',
    'speed' => 'value'
];
```

Now in the `routes`, `controller`, `views` you can access it using

```
Config::get('global-var.distance')
//views
{{ Config::get('global-var.distance') }}
// or just  config('global-var.distance');
```

And whenever you want to update your global variable, you can:

```
$data = [
    "distance" => "value"; // your input
];

Config::write('global-var', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ali, just one more question do i have to send an array of all of config file variables to update it ? can i send some thing to update only the distance variable ?

Comment: @AliAdil Yes, you can update one variable per time, no need to send all the vars.